# Declaring static generic variables in a generic class

Tags: java, list, generics, static, linked-list

I've read that you cannot declare static variables/methods inside a generic class and I really have no idea how to solve my problem or work around it so I ask for your guidance.

What I want is a generic "index" that all of my core classes will extend.
I'm creating a game-engine and an example is that I will have different gamestates who all extends `State` who in turn extends `Nexus<State>`. The reason I want the static head and tail is so that I can keep a linked list of all gamestates since they're all added to that list upon creation.

Another example is that I will have different gameobjects who all extends `GameObject` who in turn extends `Nexus<GameObject>`.

This is the index called `Nexus`:

```
public abstract class Nexus<T> 
{

    private static T head = null;
    private static T tail = null;

    private T next = null;
    private static int num = 0;

    protected Nexus() { this.Add( (T)this ); }

    public T Add( T obj )
    {

        ((Nexus)obj).next = null;
        if( num++ == 0 ) head = tail = obj;
        else             tail = ( tail.next = obj );

        return obj;

    }

}
```

If anyone got another solution or a workaround I'm all ears!

Comment: Given the name of your static fields, it is almost certainly the case that you shouldn't be using static fields here.  That would be true with or without your generics.  But where did you read that one should always avoid static members in generic classes?  Never heard that myself, and I strongly disagree.

Comment: That is weird, I got this:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at Game.main(Game.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context
 at Nexus.<clinit>(Nexus.java:13)
 ... 1 more
Java Result: 1

Comment: @Kirk A quick google search of "non-static type variable cannot be referenced from a static context" gave me tons of results that all said what I wrote, a lot coming from this site :/

Comment: @Tanax No. None of them said you can't have static variables in a generic class, and neither did the compiler, or that compiler error message, or the exception.

Comment: I'm confused heh. Line 13 is this: private static T head = null;

Comment: @Tanax: What @EJP is trying to say is that you can have static fields: `private static int num = 0;` is legal.  But it's shared between all instances of `Nexus`, so `Nexus<State>.Add()` and `Nexus<GameObject>.Add` use the same copy of `num`.  If `Nexus<State>` and `Nexus<GameObject>` share `head` (because that's how static fields work in Java) then what type would `head` be?

Comment: Right..! Okay, sorry what I meant was that I cannot have static GENERIC variables in a generic class(since I get an error at `private static T head = null;`.
And thank you, I understand a bit clearer now why I cannot do what I'm doing. However, I still cannot figure out a way to actually achieve what I want to do which is to have a generic factory class that uses a linked list between all of the classes that uses the factory class but the linked list will only be "shared" between those of the same typename

Comment: @Tanax You'll have to explain that more clearly. At the moment it sounds like a contradiction in terms. Either you are linking all the classes or you have a separate list for each class. Did you want to link all the *objects* of each class?

Comment: I will try my best, hehe. I want to link all objects of Nexus<State> so that every class that extends Nexus<State> will be placed in their own linked list and every class that extends Nexus<GameObject> will be placed in another linked list. Did that explain it better?

Comment: Static fields of generic classes cannot be of the parameterized type: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createStatic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this approach: Define a `protected abstract` method that subclasses implement to return a `static` object for *their* class.

There may be some logic issues etc, but the basics of the answer are here (ie this compiles):

**EDITED: Now [delegating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) to HeadAndTail**

```
/** <T> A subclass of Nexus */
abstract class Nexus<T extends Nexus<T>> { // This syntax lets you confine T to a subclass of Nexus
    private T next;

    protected Nexus() {
        this.add((T) this);
    }

    public T add(T obj) {
        // Delegate to HeadAndTail
        return getHeadAndTail().add(obj);
    }

    /** @return a static for the class */
    protected abstract HeadAndTail<T> getHeadAndTail();
}

/** Bundled into one Object for simplicity of API */
class HeadAndTail<T extends Nexus<T>> {
    T head = null;
    T tail = null;
    int num = 0;

    public T add(T obj) {
        obj.next = null;
        if (num++ == 0)
            head = tail = obj;
        else
            tail = tail.next = obj;

        return obj;
    }
}

class ConcreteNexus extends Nexus<ConcreteNexus> {
    // This is the static object all instances will return from the method
    private static HeadAndTail<ConcreteNexus> headAndTail = new HeadAndTail<ConcreteNexus>();

    protected HeadAndTail<ConcreteNexus> getHeadAndTail() {
        return headAndTail; // return the static
    }
}
```

Comment: That should work, but... reuse the return reference from `getHeadAndTail` instead of calling in multiple times.

Comment: That looks awesome! I will try implement it and see if it works :D

Comment: It is problematic to have the constructor of an abstract class call a virtual method.

Comment: This code worked great when I only had one type(I tested it with 2 different gamestate-classes who both extended state who extended Nexus<State>).But when I added a gameobject who extends GameObject that extended Nexus<GameObject> I got an exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Nexus.Add(Nexus.java:35)
 at Nexus.<init>(Nexus.java:16)
 at GameObject.<init>(GameObject.java:17)
 at SpaceShip.<init>(Game.java:47)
 at Game.main(Game.java:67)`
I really cannot understand why it gives me this
Nexus, 35 is: GetHeadAndTail().tail = ( GetHeadAndTail().tail.next = obj );

Comment: Oh, I know! Num is static and shared between all Nexus classes, thus head and tail will never be initialized for that typename since num is not 0.

Comment: @Tanax: Let's move `num` into the little helper class and have `Nexus` delegate to it - see updated code.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did :) Except I didn't move the add method there, is there any reasons that it is preferred to have it there instead of having it inside Nexus and do `if( getHeadAndTail().num++ == 0 )` ?

Comment: It's more object oriented - it keeps the code close to the fields it operates with.

Comment: @Bohemian, I don't at all spot the `static` keyword anywhere in your code. why not just use a normal non-static method?

Comment: @Pacerier static in my code: *private **static** HeadAndTail<ConcreteNexus> headAndTail = new HeadAndTail<ConcreteNexus>();*. Reason for `static` is in question: *The reason I want the **static** head and tail is so...*

Answer (score 12):

Java generics are quite different than C# generics.
There is type erasure, so you can't say something like `Nexus<T>.aStaticPublicField` (as in C#).
You can only say `Nexus.aStaticPublicField`.
There is no way to know what the generic type is (as you don't have an instance), so therefore you can't have a static field of type T.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I found out on all the other questions regarding this on this site. Do you know another way of accomplishing what I need or a workaround?

Comment: @Tanax: You could keep a dictionary of (head,tail) pairs, keyed by type.

Comment: @Petar, And what's wrong with `Nexus<String>.aStaticPublicField`?

Answer (score 1):

according to http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

> **Class Members** -
>   An abstract class may have static fields and static methods. You can use these static members with a class reference—for example, AbstractClass.staticMethod()—as you would with any other class.

But I haven't yet tested this myself

Comment: I'm pretty sure that tutorial predates generics.

Comment: couldn't you just put `AbstractClass.staticMethod<type>()`

Comment: Hello Tom! I don't think it's the abstract that is the fault here, but the generics ( <T> ).

Comment: thing is, looking at your code, I don't get why head and tail would be static. What you appear to be implementing is a Singly-linked list, in which case head and tail shouldn't be static or you'll only ever be able to have one instance of the class, otherwise any new instance will overwrite the head and tail for all the other instances

Comment: `((Nexus)obj).next = null;` this is a very strange line too, are you sure you want to convert the object passed in into a Nexus object?

Comment: Hmm. What I wanted to achieve was to have a static head and tail for all Nexus<something> and another static head and tail for all Nexus<somethingelse> so that all Nexus<State> I create will have their own linked list and all Nexus<GameObject> I create will have their own linked list.

Answer (score 0):

A set of static fields is not a very good way to achieve this.  I don't quite understand your requirements but it seems like a better way would be to change the signature of the constructor for this class to pass in the global index object.

That is, instead of this:

```
protected Nexus() { this.Add( (T)this ); }
```

... you could do this instead:

```
protected Nexus(GameStateIndex<T> index) { index.Add(this); }
```

This properly separates the responsibilities of tracking the game state and keeping track of the index of all game states.  (See the "[Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)".)  It also makes it explicitly clear that creation of a state object comes with a dependency on indexing that state properly.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did a poor job at explaining what I wanted in the original post but what I want to be able to do is to create .. for instance StateOne who extends State(which contains various methods). State in turn, extends Nexus<State> so what I create an instance of StateOne it will automatically get added to the internal static linked list in Nexus<State>. I also want to be able to create a SpaceShip who extends GameObject(which also contains various methods) who in turn extends Nexus<GameObject> so when I create an instance of SpaceShip it will get added to the list in Nexus<GameObject>